# Gutenberg - Dispatch action or setAttributes() on Post Save/Update action instead of onChange listener

Tags: actions, block-editor

I have a requirement to add up to 8 user selected custom colors to the list of default options when using the [Colour Palette](https://wordpress.github.io/gutenberg/?path=/story/components-colorpalette--default).

I have registered a meta that saves custom colours.

**Problem:**

I want to save custom colours when the "Update" post button is pressed instead of using the `onChange` listener, because the listener fires multiple times when the colour selector tool is dragged.

What I am doing at the moment:

```
const { isSavingPost } = useSelect( select => {
    const { isSavingPost } = select( 'core/editor' );

    return {
        isSavingPost: isSavingPost(),
    }
} );

useEffect( () => {
    if ( isSavingPost ) {
        // Logic to save custom colours.
        setAttributes( { customColors } );
    }
}, [ isSavingPost ] );
```

The problem is that when `setAttribute()` is called when "Update" is pressed, the state is updated after the post is saved, which Gutenberg considers dirty and a page reload following an "Update" shows this:

[image]

I am however able to save it if I press "Update" post twice, but this is not feasible for the end user.

Is there a way I can fire `wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost()` or `setAttributes()` when a Post is saved manually by pressing the "Update" button?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the onChange listener and do setAttributes only when value passed in onChange is different from the one in `attributes.customColors`. This is one `if` and should not penalize performance much.